# Doxygen cannot find the shared library(s) 'libclang.so.6: version `LLVM_6.0'' which it requires to run

Tags: ubuntu, installation, clang, llvm

I installed **doxygen** from the **binary distribution** for **Linux x86-64**. I'm running **Ubuntu 17.10**. The installation went smoothly.
When I try to run doxygen, it shows the following error:

> `doxygen: error while loading shared libraries: libclang.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

First I checked whether I have the latest version of `clang` installed, and I do. Next I followed the advice given in [pandabr's comment (dated Feb 7 2017)](https://github.com/mapbox/cncc/issues/6) and tried making a symbolic link called `libclang.so.6` to the existing file called `libclang-5.0.so.1` in the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. I reasoned that perhaps the doxygen documentation refers to a file called `libclang.so.6` and it was showing the error because it was unable to find the file in the given directory. Now when I try running doxygen, it shows the following error:

> `doxygen: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so.6: version 'LLVM_6.0' not found (required by doxygen)`

Given that I have the latest version of Clang installed (as of 21 Feb 2018), do I still need to install LLVM 6.0 separately? (I'm a novice, but from what I gathered from the webpages for Clang and LLVM, Clang uses LLVM as its backend and thus should contain LLVM by default.)

I looked through the [doxygen bug list on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&product=doxygen) and found [a result that matched](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792761) when I searched for `libclang`. I looked at the bug description but I'm not sure how to make use of it. Is there anything I need to change in the doxygen documents?

My principal question is, given the above error, how do I get doxygen to work? All other questions in the above body of text are subsidiary questions requiring more detailed answers. They may or may not be relevant. Since I don't know which information is relevant and which isn't, I've tried to state everything.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be dependences that apt doesn't want to install. I "fixed" the issue (also appearing on Ubuntu 16.04) by first running a

> sudo apt-get install -f

which tries to fix a broken dependency structure among the currently installed packages.

After doing that, I was able to install doxygen through apt-get, which also automatically installed its incoming dependences.